# What is the maximum amount of data that can be reliably stored in a Double that is persisted in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, double, precision

**Disclaimer:** I'm asking a crazy question, I understand it's crazy, but it has an answer, and I would like to know it.  The specific application is irrelevant, if that bothers you (or perhaps helps you sleep better at night) then pretend it's an academic question.

I understand that a [Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) ([IEE 754: "binary64"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)) itself takes up 64-bits (or 8 bytes) of raw memory space, and in memory I can pipe any raw 64-bits of data that I want in there, and it can technically be interpreted as a double -- though, some of those are "not numbers", and some are duplicates (i.e. -0 and +0 are technically different, but they compare as equal according to the spec, then there's the NaNs and the Infinities, etc...).  [My guestimate is that there's probably about 55 to 60 usable bits here if we want the data we store to always be interpretable as a sane Double value.]

And then we have to consider what persisting the data as [JSON Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6) might do to it (i.e. converting it to base 10 and rounding it to some approximation... -- I'm guessing that at best we might be able to reliable encode 40 bits of information here?)

A good Litmus test for valid values here might be:

```
    var bytes = new byte[8];
    PutDataInto(bytes);

    double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes);
    d += 0d; // Round-trip as a double
    var bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);

    if (!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(bytes, bytes2))
    {
        // already we see some byte combinations failing before the JSON conversion.
        Console.WriteLine("Double failed to store: " + d);
        Console.WriteLine($"    Input: {string.Join(string.Empty, bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Output: {string.Join(string.Empty, bytes2.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))}");
        //continue; // or break; or throw; -- whatever
    }

    var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
    var d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double>(text);

    var bytes3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(d2);
    if (!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(bytes, bytes3))
    {
        // JSON Conversion shows more failures.
        Console.WriteLine("JSON failed to store: " + d);
        Console.WriteLine($"    Input: {string.Join(string.Empty, bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Output: {string.Join(string.Empty, bytes3.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))}");
        //continue; // or break; or throw; -- whatever
    }
```

**What I have done so far:**

- I supposed that this might already be a solved problem and I tried googling it, but ... I have no idea what this type of thing might be called (as you can tell from the long ridiculous title of this question).  And I just got all sorts of nonsense that was unrelated.
- I made the approximate guesstimates shown above and looked up the specs. -- But I wanted to ask y'all before jumping right in and reading for the next 8 hours -- because A.) It might already be a solved problem. B.) Y'all are smart and might be able to figure out a sane way to store more bits there. [And it totally had nothing at all to do with C.) me being kind of lazy. ]

Comment: I have no answer, but you have to consider also the double implementation of the framework and the hardware you are using. For example dotnet may decide to use 80-bit registers to do 64-bit math on some CPU and but not on other hardware. 

So another thing you need to take in consideration is for example JSON encoding on an intel x64 machine then parsing on an ARM32 machine. The behavior can even vary between intel and AMD.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` seems to use [G17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r) ro round-trip doubles, see [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.Double.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8c64e3073e9c32e081ebd9df8141fbb2438b06d7/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.Double.cs#L101), so there should be no precision loss.

Comment: This is not a weird/crazy question

Comment: However apparently Json.NET uses [`"R"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#round-trip-format-specifier-r) not G17, see [the source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/b6dc05be5a0f4808f06ec430f3bb59b24d3fbc3e/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L265) and also [JsonConvert double precision using ToString("R") vs. ToString("G17") #1104](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1104).

Comment: As for non-finite doubles like `double.PositiveInfinity`, Json.NET controls serialization of these via [`JsonSerializerSettings.FloatFormatHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatFormatHandling.htm) while `System.Text.Json` uses [`JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.numberhandling?view=net-5.0).

Comment: RE: G17 VS R: we need to support the lowest common denominator for JSON (i.e. It may be round tripped through a browser and back).

Answer (score 1):

You have to avoid NaN and _+ infinity, because the 52bits of the fraction is ignored, and won't be round-tripped.

And if you can use the sign bit, you've got -0 and +0, which will not round-trip.

So you can safely use 10 of the 11 exponent bits, and all 52 fraction bits, or 62 bits.

JSON should round-trip all off these values.

You can actually do better if you use all 2,047 exponent values that don't indicate NaN or Inf, and the sign bit plus all the non-zero fractions, but that makes the information encoding harder.

Comment: Good answer. I denote exponentiation with `**` in this comment. So that is `2**63` different `double` values you can use with the first approach (where you take away one "whole" bit of the 64 bits). Or `2**64 - 2**53` different values of the `double` in the other approach. Good that they did not ask about the awful type `System.Decimal`.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. -- Consider that `-0` is serialized as `0` for example, because they are the same numerical value (I believe this is part of IEEE 754). -- In addition, as others have pointed out in the comments above, some JSON serializers may only write out the 15 most significant digits of a number (and I'm guessing there are be ones which write out even fewer).

Comment: Right, but that was just one example... So, like, what about the JSON implementations that only encode a certain number of significant (base 10!) digits?  I still don't think we're accounting properly for the lowest common denominator of JSON with this answer.

Comment: There's nothing about JSON per-se that is a problem here, but yes, the JSON serializer to be able to produce round-trip string decimal-formatted representations, or else you have to not use some of the least significant bits of the fraction.

Comment: From the linked article: `For Double values, the "R" format specifier in some cases fails to successfully round-trip the original value. For both Double and Single values, it also offers relatively poor performance..` and `In some cases, Double values formatted with the "R" standard numeric format string do not successfully round-trip if compiled using the /platform:x64 or /platform:anycpu switches and run on 64-bit systems.` -- Considering that the best library for .NET 4.x uses 'R' exclusively for doubles, I would assume that at least some browsers are doing something similar (if not worse).

Comment: I assumed the question was for an spy novel or somesuch.

Comment: Er... what? -- No. -- I'm trying to stuff more bits into a JSON `Number`. -- I don't have control over the clients or the spec. -- It has to be a JSON `Number`. -- The alternate approach is just using an int->lookup table and paying for the storage. -- But I wanted to explore this possibility as well.

Comment: There are no limits on a JSON number; only in JSON Serializers that try to map them to types in some language like Javascript or C#.

Comment: Exactly, apologies I didn't mean to imply that JSON had the limit -- the question was always about round tripping through serialization and deserialization for arbitrary* implementations of JSON. 
--
(*: For "arbitrary", I feel like it should be safe to define that as modern web browsers and libraries running on modern hardware. -- But I'm open to better suggestions. -- I'm not looking for an all inclusive answer, but for a safe maximum that gives me good modern compatibility and interoperability.)